# failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: errors

I get this error when I try to look at my news I tried to migrate the site to a different domain where i didn't experience this problem what do i do to fix this?[image]

Comment: does the file exist ?

Answer (score 1):

That's simple. You need to upload that file. Wp-includes/template-loader.php  That file is missing. So just re upload that there and that should work.

Comment: why does it not appear if i migrate it to a diffrent domain?

Comment: You have missed that files some how.. That is the reason

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you get this error because that file doesn't exist, uploading it is a solution.

It might not work on the other domain because you didn't move everything and wp-config is configured to show errors.

You should navigate to the main directory of your Wordpress install, open the wp-config.php file and look for a line like:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Then set it to false and check to see if the error is displayed:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

This doesn't solve the issue but should make that error not break your website anymore.